# Expanding a product to include the full graph for the diagram

Tags: ct.category-theory

Products in a category are given as limits over a very simple diagram.  The diagram is just the discrete set of objects over which you wish to define the product.  There are no morphisms in the diagram.

In any given category, and given a product over objects $J = \{ X_1, X_2 \cdots X_N \}$, one may consider the underlying graph of all morphisms between each pair of elements in $J$.  Then you can take the limit over this diagram.  Alternatively, you could choose from the plethora of different diagrams where you selected only some of the morphisms that exist between each pair of elements in $J$.  You can take the limits of each of those diagrams too.  My question is whether or not this effect has a name or use in standard literature where one:

1. Goes from just the discrete set to the set of all arrows and taking the limit of the bigger diagram
2. does some kind of iteration over all the plethora of smaller diagrams where one chooses and leads up to the largest one

What is the relationship between the very simple, discrete diagram, and the much more complicated one with all the morphisms included?

Note: [I asked this over at Math Stack and got no reply](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4316979/expanding-a-product-to-include-the-full-graph-for-the-diagram)

Comment: To take a limit over, say, the "complete diagram", you'd need to fill in the arrows with actual morphisms—you can no longer take the "complete product" of a bare family of objects.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pedagogical question, not a research one.

The simple answer is that the word **diagram** is used ambiguously.

Consider the simple example of a product $X_0\times X_1$ of two objects $X_0$ and $X_1$ in a category $\mathcal C$.

In one sense, the (**abstract**) **diagram** is the two-point discrete **graph** ${\mathbf 2}=\{0,1\}$.

There is a **functor** $X_{(-)}:{\mathbf 2}\longrightarrow{\mathcal C}$ that takes the vertices $0$ and $1$ to the objects $X_0$ and $X_1$.   This functor is also known as a **diagram**, as is its image in the category $\mathcal C$.

That's all before any products are mentioned.

In the category $\mathcal C$ we may have pairs of morphisms $X_0\longleftarrow\Gamma\longrightarrow X_1$. Such a pair is called a **cone**.

Amongst all cones there may be special ones like $X_0\longleftarrow P\longrightarrow X_1$ that have the **universal** property that you know.  We call this the **product cone** etc.

The fourth sense of the word **diagram** combines this universal cone with the image of the functor.  It is in this sense that we talk in particular, of **pullback squares**.

It is really a good idea to get out of the habit of **taking** products, pullbacks, limits, etc.  There will always (except in contrived examples) be many isomorphic product cones.  If you insist on **taking** products as an **operation** then you will quickly get tied up in questions of **Choice** and **coherence**.

The abstract diagram need not be a **discrete** graph. So for example a pullback is defined by the directed graph $\{{\mathbf 0}\leftarrow\bullet\rightarrow{\mathbf 1}\}$.

The functor takes the directed edges to morphisms.

You might instead define an abstract graph as a **category**.  There is also an intermendiate notion between graphs and categories with some specified composites; this is called a **sketch**.  In these cases the functor has to preserve the specified composites.

Using categories or sketches for abstract diagrams is particularly important for defining **filtered** diagrams and their colimits.   These are such that every finite abstract sub-diagram already has a cocone within the abstract diagram.